# Smart compare file contents of two directories based on file extensions

Tags: python, file, directory, comparison

I have two directories: one source directory which contains some files used as reference, and a target directory that contains files with the same names and some other irrelevant files. The subdirectory tree structures are the same in both directories.

```
└── reference_dir
    ├── sub_dir_1
    |   ├── sub_file_1.a
    |   └── sub_file_2.b
    └── file_1.c

└── compared_dir
    ├── sub_dir_1
    |   ├── sub_file_1.a
    |   └── sub_file_2.b
    |   └── irrelevant_file.b
    └── file_1.c
```

I want to compare the files with the same names with some specific comparison rules for each file extension. For example, I want to compare the contents of CSV files with a given tolerance for floats, or compare the PDF files based on what they look like visually, ignoring the metadata, etc.

In my case this is mainly to compare the results of [luigi](https://github.com/spotify/luigi) workflows.

Comment: Yeah I was not explicit enough, but the library can visually compare PDF files (using the diff_pdf_visually package). I fixed my answer, thanks for pointing it.

Answer (score 0):

The Python package [dir-content-diff](https://github.com/BlueBrain/dir-content-diff) does exactly this. A set of default comparators for common file extensions is provided (json, xml, yml, csv, pdf, ...) but it is easily extendable to improve existing comparators according to your needs or add new ones for other file extensions.

It is easy to use:

```
import dir_content_diff

dir_content_diff.assert_equal_trees("reference_dir", "compared_dir")
```

will display something like the following if `file1.c` is a JSON-like file (the messages are adapted to each kind of file, it would be different for PDF files for example):

```
AssertionError: The files 'reference_dir/file_1.c' and 'compared_dir/file_1.c' are different:
Added the value(s) '{"2": 0}' in the '[b]' key.
Changed the value of '[a]' from 1 to 2.
Changed the value of '[b][0]' from 1 to 10.
```

It is also possible to get the differences in a dictonary to post-process them:

```
import dir_content_diff

dir_content_diff.compare_trees("reference_dir", "compared_dir")
```

would return the following:

```
{
    'file_1.c': (
        'The files \'reference_dir/file_1.c\' and \'compared_dir/file_1.c\' are different:\n'
        'Added the value(s) \'{"2": 0}\' in the \'[b]\' key.\n'
        'Changed the value of \'[a]\' from 1 to 2.\n'
        'Changed the value of \'[b][0]\' from 1 to 10.'
    )
}
```

It is possible to pass a tolerance for float comparison and many other things that I let you discover in the [documentation](https://dir-content-diff.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) :)

**Disclaimer**: I am the main author of this package.